# To filter specific records

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement to filter (flatfile) only those records  who has the colA values as 1,2,3,4,5,6 and also ColB as 'N'. The records that satisfy this condition from  the source file should process to target.
Earlier it was said to check for only one value from colA. So therefore i applied

```
IIF(COLA='1' AND COLB'N',TRUE)
```

How to filter with multiple values for the same column? I am new to informatica power center.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this in an expression : using `OR` logical operator or using `IN` function.

With `OR`

```
IIF((COLA='1' OR COLA='2' OR COLA='3' OR COLA='4' OR COLA='5) AND COLB='N',TRUE)
```

Parenthesis are essential to group conditions on `COLA`.

With `IN`

```
IIF(IN(COLA,'1','2,'3','4','5') AND COLB='N',TRUE)
```

I find this one easier to read.

Comment: = sign was missing from COLB'N' formula.